# Set value of TextField from another window in javafx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a TextField set on Action(press enter) to open another fxml window that shows a table of choices(hundreds of choices). Basically I need that 2nd window to set the text of the textfield on the first window.

```
@FXML //this pops out a 2nd window where i can choose a person. Set from Scene Builder
private void pickperson(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/personpicker.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
} 

@FXML //when i click "use selected" this gets executed
private void use(ActionEvent event) {
    Person person0 = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int id = person0.getId();
    String name = person0.getNAME();
    final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString(Integer.toString(id)); //i tried clipboard but when i paste, nothing is pasted
    Stage stage = (Stage) useselected.getScene().getWindow();//closes the window
    stage.close();
}
```

I have a table on the 2nd window with a button labeled: "use selected". I want to make it so that the moment click "use selected", the window closes and at the same time set the text field from the selection.

Edit:
I got the clipboard to work by adding

```
Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
```

Now, I just need to paste the value directly after the window closes; as if CRTL+V was pressed.

Comment: You don't need to use the system clipboard in order to update the contents of a text field in one [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) when you perform an action in a second `Stage`. In order to show you how to do that, it would help if you posted a [mcve]. Include both the java code and the contents of your FXML files.

Comment: @Abra I hope its not too late. I made a barebones version of what I am trying to do. https://github.com/alexislyndon/testcodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the "parent" `Stage`, i.e. the one containing the `TextField`, is the owner of the `Stage` displaying the three buttons. Hence you can simply call method [`getOwner()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getOwner()) in the child `Stage` in order to access the parent `Stage`. Once you have a reference to the parent `Stage`, you can access its nodes and manipulate them.

I only changed two files in your code.

1. `Parent.fxml` - I added the *id* attribute to `TextField`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="266.0" prefWidth="394.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.ParentController">
   <children>
      <TextField id="txtFld" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="121.0" onAction="#picker" />
      <Label layoutX="140.0" layoutY="86.0" text="Press enter to choose" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

2. `ChildController.java` - I added the method `handleEvent(int)`

```java
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChildController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane ap;
    @FXML
    private Button btnone;
    @FXML
    private Button btntwo;
    @FXML
    private Button btnthree;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    private void one(ActionEvent event) {
        handleEvent(1);
    }

    @FXML
    private void two(ActionEvent event) {
        handleEvent(2);
    }

    @FXML
    private void three(ActionEvent event) {
        handleEvent(3);
    }

    private void handleEvent(int chosenNumber) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();
        Stage owner = (Stage) stage.getOwner();
        Scene scene = owner.getScene();
        Parent root = scene.getRoot();
        TextField txtFld = (TextField) root.lookup("#txtFld");
        txtFld.setText(String.valueOf(chosenNumber));
        stage.close();
    }
}
```